# How to flatten this multiple rows into one?

Tags: sql-server

I have data like this: (table name: `Activities`)

```
ActivityId   CreatedOn  TypeId
1            2017-01-01 1
1            2017-01-02 1
1            2017-01-02 2
2            2017-01-01 3
```

Where `Type` is a lookup value: (table name: `Types`)

```
TypeId   Name
1        Question
2        Answer
3        Comment
```

Basically it's an activity history table.

I want to turn the above tables into a grouped sum row for types, for each `ActivityId`, like this:

```
ActivityId   QuestionCount   AnswerCount   CommentCount
1            2               1             0
2            0               0             1
```

I know the answer is probably pretty simple, but it's eluding me for some reason.

Any help? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple join and conditional aggregation should do the trick (I suspect you were over-thinking it)

```
Select ActivityID
      ,QuestionCount = sum(case when Name='Question' then 1 else 0 end)
      ,AnswerCount   = sum(case when Name='Answer'   then 1 else 0 end)
      ,CommentCount  = sum(case when Name='Comment'  then 1 else 0 end)
 From  Activities A
 Join  Types B on A.TypeId=B.TypeId
 Group By ActivityId
```

Returns

```
ActivityID  QuestionCount   AnswerCount CommentCount
1           2               1           0
2           0               0           1
```

You could also do it without the Join... Just less readable

```
Select ActivityID
      ,QuestionCount = sum(case when TypeId=1 then 1 else 0 end)
      ,AnswerCount   = sum(case when TypeId=2 then 1 else 0 end)
      ,CommentCount  = sum(case when TypeId=3 then 1 else 0 end)
 From  @Activities A
 Group By ActivityId
```

You could also try a PIVOT

```
Select ActivityID
      ,[1] as QuestionCount
      ,[2] as AnswerCount
      ,[3] as CommentCount
From  (Select ActivityId,TypeID,1 as Cnt From @Activities) A
Pivot (count(Cnt) For TypeId in ([1],[2],[3]) ) p
```

Comment: Ahh, clever! I was over-thinking it :) Thankyou!!

Comment: btw - is this the most performant way? I'm going to have to run this query a lot, and there will millions of activity records. Not opposed to changing schema

Comment: @RPM1984 I would then opt for the the second option without the JOIN.  I can't think of a faster approach.